# Set template for block if there are blocks with the same name

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change template for 'form' block in such layout:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
...
    <reference name="root">
            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create" name="content">
                <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_form" template="sales/order/create/form.phtml" name="form">
...
                        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="shipping_method">
                            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml" name="form" />
                        </block>
                        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="billing_method">
                            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method_form" template="sales/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml" name="form" />
                        </block>
                        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_newsletter" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="newsletter">
                            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_newsletter_form" template="sales/order/create/newsletter/form.phtml" name="form" />
                        </block>
...
```

I do

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
    <reference name="form">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>my_module/sales/order/create/form.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```

But this does not work. I think because block with name form exist in several places more after. I just want to change it in block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_form". How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

@input

Rewrite of block is not the best appoach. It is better to observe 'core_block_abstract_to_html_before' event and change template there I think. Like:

```
if ($observer->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form) {
    $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('my_module/newtemplate.phtml');
}
```

This works and is better because you will not get modules conflict if somebody else will rewrite this block. But I thought that may be possible on layout level..

Comment: I agree with the sentiment but for such a general observer to catch one admin block you are generating and extra call for every block on the website including the frontend. Consider using the `adminhtml_block_html_before` event. Annoying this problem stems from some Magento developers laziness!

Comment: Usually I put observer to admin section (not to global), so the result will be the same I think as if I use adminhtml_block_html_before

Answer (score 2):

Whilst not the prettiest solution I too do not know of a way of setting a template on a non unique form reference.

Warning this is pretty gross, and I am really not sure of the side affects and for some reason calling setTemplate in the constructor is not enough I guess this is being called at a earlier or later stage than the parents

```
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('my_module/sales/order/create/form.phtml');

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Add the write to your Module

```
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_create_form>My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Form</sales_order_create_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

I really hope there is a better solution than this.

Comment: I posted my solution that I think is better to answers. But this is not directly what I want, this is not layout update.

Answer (score 0):

your right, thats the reason why its not working.
i can't think of a clean way because of this bad naming.

However there are several options that are not clean but will work:

**1 option**: copy the whole `sales.xml` into your own admin layout folder and change the template there directly.

**2 option**: "rewriting" "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form" and set the template from the code

**3 option**: subscribe to "adminhtml_block_html_before" and listen for the right block and change the template then.

However if you write a community module non of these options are really good.
if it is your own project i would go for option 1

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For overwriting the `form` name form.phtml file from the `billing_method` you should do the following:

In the `config.xml`:

```
<core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
   <observers>
       <mymodule_core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
              <class>MyModule_Model_MyPath</class>
              <method>setTemplateFile</method>
       </mymodule_core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
   </observers>
</core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
```

and in your observer:

```
 public function setTemplateFile(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
 {
        if ($observer->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Billing_Method_Form) {
            $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('mymodule/sales/order/create/billing/method/form.phtml');
        }
 }
```